# Fastest way to search string in df column/ list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs:
df_1: 100K rows.
Each row represents information about a string (unique).
The first column is that string.
The rest of the columns are attributes about it.

df_2: 10M rows.
Each row represents information about a string (unique).
The first column is that string.
The rest of the columns are attributes about it.

I want to check if string from df_1 exists in df_2. (do that for all strings in df_1).
However, I want to minimize the running time. Are there ways to optimize the code I wrote:

```
def check_exists(keyword):

    keyword = keyword[0]
    print('check if keyword exists: ' + keyword)
    
    if (keyword in list_10m_keywords):
        df_1.loc[df_1['keyword'] == keyword, 'exists'] = 'TRUE'
        print('exists')
    else:
        print('not exists')


# Load df_1
# Save as global be used in other scopes
global df_1 
df_1 = pd.read_pickle('keywords_data_100k.pkl')


# Load and convert df_2 column to list
# Save as global be used in other scopes
global list_10m_keywords
df_2 = pd.read_pickle('keywords_data_10m.pkl')
list_10m_keywords = df_2 ['keyword'].tolist()
# Set not exists for all keywords up front
df['exists'] = 'FALSE'

# Iterate all rows in df_1, check if exists in df_2
[check_exists(keyword) for keyword in zip(df_1['keyword'])]
```

Comment: What about [merging](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) the frames on 'keyword'? An inner merge would give shared values. A merge with indicator on df_2 could be used to see which values were contained in both df_1 and df_2 and be rather performant. Also the pandas [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas-dataframe-isin) could work here. For data of this size converting to python lists takes away the performance optimizations of having a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @HenryEcker when I'm trying to merge I'm getting "cannot allocate memory for array"

Comment: Again, those were just ideas as I have very minimal information about what your DataFrames look like.

Comment: @HenryEcker Sure, thanks! As for DataFrame.isin(values), how would you use it performance-wise? Is it better to set series as argument or df as an argument?

Comment: It would be something like: `df_2['exists'] = df_2['keywords'].isin(df_1['keywords'])`

Comment: @HenryEcker Works with my machine's memory and super-fast! Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem here is that you are searching `df_1` **twice**, first to check for existence, then again to match the string value. You could combine both of these steps to do something like:

`df_2['exists'] = [True if x in df_1['keyword'] else False for x in df_2['keyword']]`

You can probably replace your `check_keywords()` function with just that line, and it should process much faster.